# Yaml file addressing in GAE using Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, yaml

Here is the file structure :

```
--src
-----\app.yaml
-----\bl
-----\bl\calc.html
-----\calc.py
-----\Main.py
```

I want to get to this address "localhost/bl/calc.html" and here is my yaml file:

```
 - url: /bl
      static_dir: bl
 - url: /bl/.*
      script: calc.py
  - url: /.*
      script: Main.py
```

In the Main.py I have this :

```
   from calc import Calc

    application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
      ('/', MainPage),
      ('/bl/calc', Calc)
    ], debug=True)
```

But I got just "This webpage is not found" for both http://localhost/bl/calc and http://localhost/bl/calc.html

I got really confused With this YAML file and GAE
I Dont know how to fix it. Should I have same application config in Calc file ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directives in app.yaml are evaluated in order, top to bottom. Because you have a `static_dir` directive for `/bl/` before the script handlers for `/bl/` and `.*`, any requests for that path will be satisfied by the static directory, not the script. Decide which you want - static or script - and add only that to app.yaml.

Comment: Thats true, Now its working but I have another problem THANKS

Answer (score 0):

The yaml file tells what file to run for a given path. Since you're setting up a WSGIApplication in Main.py that will handle requests to /bl/calc with your Calc object, you don't need the lines in your app.yaml file specifying calc.py. Remove those lines and your program should work.

Comment: That's true, but isn't the root cause of his current problem.